# Get referring domain from HTML5 Audio Tag Streaming URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, referrer

Part of a site I am working on at the moment requires Audio/Video previews.

These are server from a different server to the main site.

The Streaming URL is of the form:

www.myserver.com/Preview.aspx?e=I_AM_AN_ENCRYPTED_KEY

The Key is generated by the server that hosts the file, not the site on which the previews are actually displayed. It's kind of an API.

Part of the security to stop these previews being played anywhere except this website is supposed to check the domain which is requesting this, but it seems that `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` is `NULL` when requested from an HTML5 video/audio element.

Without posting the domain along with the Key to the API, is there any way that I can get the referring URL on the receiving server, server side?

EDIT:

To clarify:

- There is a website with HTML5 elements which are directed to a URL on a different server, the URL and key is provided by this server (not the website)
- When the API server receives a request to stream the preview it checks the Key (which basically tells it what to play) and also checks for the referring domain against a list of allowed domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - in case anyone cares...

Simply replace:

`ReferringDomain = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer`

with :

`ReferringDomain = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("Referer")`

Sorted! :)